# DJANGO, Campo del ModelForm que no se muestra pero se requiere

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, django-forms, crm

Estoy diseñando un formulario para el modelo "Orden" con un ModelForm, todo funciona bien excepto cuando se va a guardar, me arroja el siguiente error:

> (1048, "Column 'cantidad' cannot be null")

El problema esta en que el formulario no me muestra dicha columna para empezar ya que este campo es parte del intermediario de muchos a muchos con los productos. Entonces mi duda es, ¿Como hacer para mostrar esos campos del modelo intermediario que debo rellenar en el formulario? o cual es la forma mas comun de crear formularios cuando se trabaja en muchos a muchos? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Aca esta el formulario y los modelos:

formulario:

```
class OrdenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orden
        fields = '__all__'
```

Modelos:

```
class Orden(models.Model):
    id_orden = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    creado_en = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    num_orden = models.IntegerField()
    id_producto = models.ManyToManyField(Producto, through='Orden_prod')
```

El cual tiene una relación de muchos a muchos con el modelo:

```
class Producto(models.Model):
   id_producto = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   creado_en = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   nombre_producto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   descripcion_prod = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Por medio del siguiente modelo intermediario:

```
class Orden_Prod(models.Model):
creado_en = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
cantidad = models.IntegerField()
precio_unit = models.DecimalField
empaque = models.CharField(max_length=15)
id_inventario = models.ForeignKey(Producto,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
id_orden = models.ForeignKey(Orden, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```